# Disk is almost full after restoring to factory defaults

Tags: macos, disk-utility, storage

After restoring my Macbook pro 2016 (MacOS Catalina 10.15.2) to factory setting, it told me that my disk is almost full, but that is highly unlikely, as I have just restored it !
[image]

Here is `diskutil list`:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         250.7 GB   disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +250.7 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD - Data     200.7 GB   disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 104.0 MB   disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                528.5 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      5.4 GB     disk1s4
   5:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD - Data     30.5 GB    disk1s5
   6:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            10.9 GB    disk1s6
```

How should I solve this crisis?

Comment: How did you perform the restore to factory? Can you add the output of `diskutil list` and `diskutil apfs list` in your question please? [edit]

Comment: @grg btw, this "other volumes in container" (~200GB) is approximately same size as what my hard disk contained before my restoration....

Comment: I’m guessing you reinstalled the OS and didn’t actually do an erase install. See my answer. I’ll edit my question to have Apple’s procedure for erase install. If you print that out and take notes, it will help us help you rather than guessing what operations happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The install didn’t do well. If you have a good backup, I would perform another erase install (or the first erase install if you just reinstalled the OS. Apple doesn’t define a factory reset, so we have no clue what that means unless you reference a written process you performed).

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904

*What makes an erase install is step 2 - format the disk.* Your disk wasn’t formatted correctly. Specifically which of your `disk1s1` and `disk1s5` contains your user data is in question. You should only have one Macintosh HD - Data per Catalina system volume and not two.

Answer (score 1):

To troubleshoot this, here are the questions I’d ask:

What partition is it booting from? If your booting from disk1s6 it's no wonder it giving you the message as it's only 10.9GB in size and the OS will easily fill that up with updates and other stuff.

Also, define "restoring to factory settings" as this could mean different things. Did you erase the partition that your OS is installed on and reinstalled Catalina on it?

Comment: So many questions that this should be a comment and not an answer.

Comment: This needs a serious edit to go out on the limb and answer what to do. Unless you make this into how to troubleshoot, it is a bit like playing 20 questions. That’s never good in comments or in answer.

Comment: Did I post it as an answer? That wasn't what I wanted to do. Kinda new here so I'm still finding my way. Could a moderator change it to a comment? Or can I do it myself? I looked but could find anything.

Comment: thanks for your help. In general, you could comment below the question, and you could delete your question (not sure for new user though)

Comment: No don’t delete this. A small edit makes it some good troubleshooting with explanation. It’s not much different than my answer TBH